# Tablesorter resorting in combination with setInterval and CSS3 animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I make an application for betting where I load new JSON data on every 3s and if it is necessary, add, delete or update some rows. I use jQuery tablesorter plugin for table sorting by a column. It's working great, but I have one specific case. If there is a result change, I add "highlight" CSS class so that row will pulse about 8 seconds in orange using CSS3 animation and after completing of animation, that class is removed. This works perfectly, but if I use tablesorter resort option, that animation starts again on every 3s and practically never ends, because it lasts longer than set interval (3s is less than 8s). So, if I put resort option to false, the problem with animation doesn't exist and it will be continuous until it's finished, but I would like to use resort option on every update.

To better explain the situation, here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/savicmi/h9gpqrwn/15/ that demonstrates the problem. If it is added a row with Basketball in it, that row's background will pulse. It seems that tablesorter redraws table's body if it is resort = true, and probably it is the reason for starting CSS3 animation from the beginning instead of continuous duration up to the end of an animation. How can this be solved?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".table-liveevents").tablesorter({ 
    sortList: [[1,0]],
    ignoreCase: true,
    textExtraction: {
      '.sorter-date' : function(node, table, cellIndex){ 
        var dat =   node.textContent.split(/\/|\s|\:/);
        var date = dat[1]+'/'+dat[0]+'/'+dat[2]+' '+dat[3]+':'+dat[4];
        return new Date(date).getTime();                        
      }
    },
    resort: true
  });

var data = {
  "live_ev": [
    {
      "id": 206622,
      "date": "28/06/2017 11:55",
      "name": "Evtimova, Dia - Dulgheru, Alexandra",
      "sport": "Tennis"
    },
    {
      "id": 206553,
      "date": "28/06/2017 11:40",
      "name": "Sabanin, Yan - Matsukevitch, Denis",
      "sport": "Tennis",
    },
    {
      "id": 206754,
      "date": "28/06/2017 13:05",
      "name": "Crvena Zvezda - Partizan",
      "sport": "Basketball"
    }]
};

    function addRow(data, table) {

    if (table.find('tr#r_'+data.id).length == 0) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');      
        tr.id = 'r_' + data.id;
        tr.className = 'details';
        for(var j = 1; j <= 3; j++){
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode( data[Object.keys(data)[j]]));
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }       
        table.find('tbody').append(tr); 
    }
    }

  var isFirst = true;
  setInterval(function() {

    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.live_ev.length);
    var $basketball = $('.table-liveevents').find('tr:has(td:contains("Basketball"))');

    addRow(data.live_ev[i], $('.table-liveevents'));

    if ($basketball.length > 0 && isFirst==true) {
      $basketball.addClass("highlight").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
      });
      isFirst = false;
    }

    $('.table-liveevents').trigger("update");    

  }, 3000);     

});
```

Comment: I [answered your question here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1423).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much :)